# Disable Xdebug in docker container before running PHPUnit via PhpStorm

Tags: docker, phpunit, phpstorm, xdebug

I configured PhpStorm according to this tutorial: [PHPUnit for PhpStorm](https://blog.alejandrocelaya.com/2017/02/01/run-phpunit-tests-inside-docker-container-from-phpstorm/)

I can run my PHPUnit test successfully, so this is working.

The problem is, in my docker container I have enabled Xdebug which I need sometimes. Normally, I `docker exec` into the container and run the tests there. Xdebug slows down the tests heavily, so I do `phpdismod -s cli xdebug` before I run my tests. Then the tests run 100x faster!

Now I want to achieve the same behaviour when I run the tests through PhpStorm. PhpStorm brings up an own docker container where it runs the tests. I don't know how I can tell PhpStorm to run `phpdismod -s cli xdebug` before starting PHPUnit. Is there a way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

According to the link you mentioned, there is a way to set image name like `shlink_shlink_php:latest` for example.

What you need to do is to add `entrypoint.sh` in your own image and based on envrionment variable you may enable or disable the debugging mode for example:

```
export DEBUG="${DEBUG:-on}"
if [ "$DEBUG" == "off" ]; then
  phpdismod -s cli xdebug
fi
```

So by default the debug value is `on` which means to leave the xdebug mode active. however if you passed an environment value called `DEBUG` with value `off` then it will disable xdebug.

You can pass environment variables as explained in [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/docker.html#using_env_vars).

Alternatively, you may check the following options which mentioned in [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-remote-interpreters.html) for example try to pass `-dxdebug.remote_enable=0` through php additional options from PHPStorm (I am not sure if preventing connection to remote interpreter will be the same as disabling the debugger as i am not expert in this part but you may check it too )